# How to unzip a windows-built .tar.gz in linux?

Tags: linux, windows, zip

i wanna transfer files from my windows pc to linux server.

suppose i have a file structure like this:

```
img /
    logo.gif
css /
    style.css
index.php
```

i tar.gz the directory, then upload, and then `tar-xvzf` the uploaded file. but the result is 3 file in root like this:

```
img\logo.gif
css\style.css
index.php
```

when i use zip instead of tar.gz it breaks the structure. i.e. it unzip some directories as empty files. fr examples it makes an empty file named img.

what's the reliable solution to transfer files between windows and linux?

Comment: What `tar` are you using that generates such broken files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me that looks like the tool you're using on windows is broken. A tarball is a tarball and the OS you make it on should not matter.

I recommend using p7zip though, on windows.

If you're more concerned with just moving the files, winscp is a nice GUI over scp. If your linux box is running sshd you can just transfer them over the network.

Comment: thanks. i use sepeedcommander to make archives. i will try with another one to see the result.

Comment: yes. i used 7p to zip in windows and it worked in linux. thanks.
but a note. just tar.az worked. the .zip had problem still.